# How to keep mouse at corners when drag a rectangle?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm looking for a way to solve this problem. I had a rectangle and I can drag at 4 corners to scale. But when I drag rectangle, my mouse icon didn't stay at corner, and I want It stay at corner when I'm dragging like this.

This is my img url

[image]

This is my code block.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    title: qsTr("Test Crop")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    property var selection: undefined
    property int rulersSize: 18
    property double newheight: recframe.height
    property double newwidth: recframe.width
    property double oldwidth: recframe.width
    property double oldheight: recframe.height

    Rectangle {
        x:parent.width / 4
        y: parent.height / 4
        width: parent.width / 2
        height: parent.width / 2
        id: recframe
        border {
            width: 2
            color: "steelblue"
        }
        color: "#354682B4"

        //rec corner in top left
        Rectangle {
            width: 18
            height: 18
            color: "steelblue"
            anchors.verticalCenter:parent.top
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.left
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                drag{ target: parent; axis: Drag.XAxis }
                onMouseXChanged: {
                    if(drag.active){
                        newheight = newheight-mouseY
                        var c=recframe.scale/oldheight * newheight
                        recframe.scale = c
                        newwidth = oldwidth * newheight/ oldheight
                        recframe.x += (oldwidth - newwidth)/ 2
                        recframe.y += mouseY / 2
                        oldheight = newheight
                        oldwidth = newwidth
                    }
                }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, even professional graphics software doesn't lock the mouse cursor. That is really not necessary, but if you really want to fake it, you can hide the real mouse cursor and draw a fake one wherever you want. But your real problem is your scaling algorithm, which is buggy as hell.

Comment: Have you tried [`drag.threshold: 0`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#drag.threshold-prop)? Sidenote: Why do you do all that stuff with JS? Maybe there is a error in it as well...